# flutter location permissions prompt not appearing

Tags: flutter, user-permissions

im trying to use the geolocator package on flutter, ive read its documentation and accordingly inserted the codes
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`

i stopped running the app and rerunned it. but it still says
`E/flutter (10375): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: User denied permissions to access the device's location.`

is there something im missing? any help appreciated[image]

Comment: Please also include the Flutter code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 8.0.0 of the geolocator plugin, the implicit requesting of permissions when calling the `Geolocator.getCurrentPosition()` or `Geolocator.getPositionStream()` methods have been removed. Starting from version 8.0.0 it is necessary to explicitly call the `Geolocator.requestPermission()` method before calling the `Geolocator.getCurrentPosition()` or `Geolocator.getPositionStream()` methods.

The suggested flow looks something like this:

```dart
Future<Position> getLocation() {
  // Test if location services are enabled.
  bool serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    // Location services are not enabled don't continue
    // accessing the position and request users of the 
    // App to enable the location services.
    return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
  }

  LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately. 
      return Future.error(Exception('Location permissions are permanently denied.'));
    } 

    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      // Permissions are denied, next time you could try
      // requesting permissions again (this is also where
      // Android's shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale 
      // returned true. According to Android guidelines
      // your App should show an explanatory UI now.
      return Future.error(Exception('Location permissions are denied.'));
    }
  }

  // When we reach here, permissions are granted and we can
  // continue accessing the position of the device.
  return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
}
```

Comment: thank you! the tutorial im following is quite outdated and it didnt use this function so i thought this wasnt needed.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above mentioned, you must update the requirements of implementation, you should ask for geolocation permission, and let the user allow it or not

please see the documentation : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/flutter-geolocator-plugin